# Can't link java into html/html file not replacing text

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html and javascript files

```js
function saved() {
    "use strict";
    var description;
    description = document.getElementById("description").value;
}
function savedd() {
    "use strict";
    var due_date;
    due_date = document.getElementById("due_date").value;
}
function saverd() {
    "use strict";
    var reminder_date = document.getElementById("reminder_date").value;
}
document.getElementsByClassName("result").innerHTML = "My new text!";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center">

      <!-- Div align in the middle -->
      <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center">
          <form>
           Description:<br>
           <input type="text" name="description" onchange="saved()"><br>
              <br>
              <br>
            Due Date:<br>
           <input type="date" name="due_date" onchange="savedd()" ><br>
              <br>  
              <br>
            Reminder Date: <br>
           <input type="text" name="reminder_date" onchange="saverd()"><br>
          </form>
      </div>
        <div class="result"> PlaceHolder</div>
</div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src="editpage.js"></script>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

I want it to eventually replace the PlaceHolder text with the Description stored data so that I know that that part of the script is working properly so I can call on it later, but now it just sticks to saying PlaceHolder

Comment: Sorry, how does this involve coding in Java? I see JavaScript but not Java -- am I missing something? Why the [tag:java] tag?

Comment: Removed it sorry, pretty late here :p

Comment: That works! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `getElementsByClassName("result")` to `getElementsByClassName("result")[0]`. Your original call returns a collection of nodes, you want to set the innerHTML on a specific node.

Here's a fixed version of your snippet:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].innerHTML = "My new text!";
```

```html
<div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center">

  <!-- Div align in the middle -->
  <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center">
    <form>
      Description:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="description" onchange="saved()">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>Due Date:
      <br>
      <input type="date" name="due_date" onchange="savedd()">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>Reminder Date:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="reminder_date" onchange="saverd()">
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="result">PlaceHolder</div>
</div>
```